# MOSFET for low voltage (single cell NiMH)

Tags: mosfet, battery-operated

[image]I would like to switch on a boost converter when a pushbutton is pressed. The power source is a single NiMH battery, so minimum 0.9V. Would [this MOSFET](https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/discrete/transistor/mosfet/ru1j002yn-e.pdf) work with a gate voltage in that range? My maximum current draw will be around 100 mA. The other option would be to use a boost converter with an enable pin, but I haven't found one that is suitable for my application, so I'd rather use an external switch.

Comment: What do you want to switch with the FET exactly? Do you want to connect some kind of device to the battery with it?

Comment: Why not just put the switch in series with the battery?

Comment: Sorry, I've added a schematic above to show what I have in mind. What I haven't shown is that once the boost converter is enabled it will power up an MCU that will then drive the MOSFET gate to keep the boost enabled once the pushbutton is released. I was going to tackle that part next, but I first wanted to see if a MOSFET like this is appropriate for this application.

Comment: Doh! Yes, I see now that I could connect the pushbutton in series with the battery, and then I can use a more common MOSFET switched from a GPIO to maintain the battery connection once the button is released.

Comment: You shouldn't use N-channel MOSFETs as high-side switches.  The gate-to-source voltage will be far lower than 0.9 V once it starts to turn on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An N-channel MOSFET won't work in this application, as evildemonic already pointed out in the comments. The source potential of the MOSFET will always be lower than the battery voltage by at least the MOSFET's threshold voltage, which means that of your 0.9V battery voltage, roughly 0V will actually arrive at the load.

What you need is called a high-side load switch IC. Example: Toshiba TCK207G.