# Best way to disconnect voltage source from GPIO when MCU is powered down

Tags: mosfet, battery-operated, analog-switch

I need to measure a battery voltage (0.9 - 1.5 V) with a GPIO input, and the battery voltage is still present when the MCU is powered down. What is the recommended way to disconnect the battery from the GPIO to protect the MCU? My understanding of transistors is limited, but it seems that one option is to control a MOSFET with another GPIO. However, I suspect that I can't use a high-side MOSFET by itself because there's not enough voltage difference between the GPIO (3.0 V) and the battery voltage. Is that correct? Is there a simple transistor circuit that you would recommend? Alternatively, would an analog switch IC be a good choice for this?

Comment: By GPIO, do you mean ADC of the MCU?

Comment: Correct, an analog input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually possible to use a high-side MOSFET just as you already suggested. There are MOSFETs which can operate with very low gate voltage. One such MOSFET is the RU1J002YN. You don't even need an additional GPIO, you can just use the MCU's supply voltage to control the MOSFET. This will ensure that the voltage on the ADC pin is always lower than the MCU's supply voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fD4www.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This works because the difference between the battery voltage (1.5V) and the MCU supply voltage (3.0V) is always bigger than the MOSFET's minimum gate voltage (0.9V). Therefore, the MOSFET will always be fully turned on when the MCU supply voltage is present, and turned off when it is absent. The 9 Ohm on-state resistance of the MOSFET is good enough for just connecting an ADC pin since almost no current will flow through it anyway.

Of course, this doesn't work with any random MOSFET, but it's a very simple solution that only requires a single slightly specialized part. (And it's quite cheap - the RU1J002YN costs 5 cents in bulk quantities.)

Edit: Actually, this is the same MOSFET that you already wanted to use in one of your earlier questions - that's how I know about it :)

It works as a high-side switch here because you have more voltage available - 3V is plenty compared to the 0.9V you had available in that [other question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/644564/mosfet-for-low-voltage-single-cell-nimh).

Comment: Wow, great! Thanks so much. In the interest of learning, is it the gate threshold voltage in the datasheet that is the critical value? Does that need to be lower than the difference between the gate voltage and the source voltage, or just lower than the gate voltage?

Comment: The critical value is the gate-to-source voltage and on-resistance. The MOSFET datasheet specifies the maximum on-resistance at various gate-to-source voltages. In the case of the RU1J002YN, the datasheet says that it'll have at most 9 Ohms of resistance when 0.9V (or more) is applied between gate and source. With 1.5V, this already drops down to 2.8 Ohms. If a MOSFET's datasheet doesn't specify an on-resistance for the gate-source voltage you want to apply (or lower), you better choose another one.

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Comment: Could you explain the purpose of the 10K pulldown here? Would it have any affect on the ADC readings? Could it be a higher value so it's not drawing too much power if I just connect the gate to Vcc so the battery is connected continuously? Thanks!

Comment: The resistor is just there to bleed leakage current to ground when the FET is off. You can increase its value dramatically if you want to - 100k or even 1M should be totally fine. You could even remove it entirely if you trust the ESD protection diodes of the MCU to take care of the leakage current.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I'll just increase the value.